# Invalid runtimeconfig.json in .NET Benchmark

Tags: c#, benchmarking

I have simple benchmark project(using BenchmarkDotNet lib) on .net core 3.1 that print Hello message to console. When project on disk D root the benchmark runs successfully, but if my project deeper in file system it fails with invalid runtimeconfig.json. Please, help me.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I just enabled long path support in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misleading error, the issue is that the full path to `runtimeconfig.json` gets too long. As you have pointed out in your comment, enabling long path support (or shortening the full path) resolves the issue.

For more information: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/1328